# Range length in python

Tags: python, range

I'm trying to make a program that spells an entered word in reverse. I finally got it to work, but I don't understand why it works. Here is the working program:

```py
    def reverse(text):
    length = len(text)
    text = list(text)
    new = ["None"] * length
    for i in range(0, length):
        new[i] = text[length - i - 1]
    return "".join(new)
return new
```

Shouldn't making `i` `range(0, length)` be one character longer than the original word? Ex. if the original word is four characters, `range(0, length)` would be five characters, wouldn't it? Seems like the range should be `(0, length - 1)`, but that didn't work! Could someone please explain why?

Comment: Did you not print `range(5)` to test your theory?

Comment: It would not, range gives you 0,...,length -1

Comment: The end of the range is exclusive

Comment: By the way `return text[::-1]` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python

Comment: `for x in range(0,5): print(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python ranges go *until* it is reached, stopping when it does.

Writing a range out as a for loop looks like this:

```
for i in range(a, b, c):

for (int i = a; i < b; i += c) {
```

So it doesn't include the end point.

Note that the `<` means that it doesn't include `b`. You might be thinking of it as `<=`.

And, in this case, you can just use the built-in reversed, or slice by `[::-1]` (From the end, to the start, going back by a character each time.)

Also note that `range(0, x)` is equivalent to `range(x)`,

Answer (score 1):

Once it reaches `length` the loop ends. For example

```
str1 = "hello"
length = len(str1) #length = 5  
for i in range(0,length) # will loop from 0 to 4.
    print(length)
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

in the example, the loop will run for 1 less than length

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are learning Python (so am I, and have been for over 20 years now - there's always more to learn!) so first of all congratulate yourself on having produced code that works!

If you have used string slicing then you may know that `x[:]` creates a new copy of the sequence `x` (string, lists and tuples are all considered to be sequences), containing exactly the same elements. You may even also know that you can use a "stride" as the third element of a slice.

What you may *not* know is that using a stride of `-1` will iterate backwards through the elements. So a shorter version of your `reverse` function might read

```
def reverse(x):
    return x[::-1]
```

It isn't unusual for newer Python users to discover that efficient ways of doing things they have been doing inefficiently are built into the language, so consider this not a criticism of your code but a suggestion for possible improvement.